# Use a single dictionary object instead of multiple method parameters (similar to args[] in Main method)

Tags: c#

Can a single dictionary object be used in place to replace method parameters (similar to args in Main method) is this a good idea or if bad? what would be a better approach than this?

```
private async Task<OperationResult> AddOrUpdateRecord(Dictionary<string, object> args)
{
    args.TryGetValue("record", out object record);
    ...
    ... etc

    var recordExists = new RecordExists(record as RecordDto, _dnsCommonActionsRepo);
}
```

Comment: The biggest disadvantage is that you don't know the keys of the dictionary. There is no compile time guarantee that the referred key does exist.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from doing this with every method in your code. But is there a reason (i.e. specific use case) *why* you'd want to do this instead of using explicit parameters? (e.g. reducing amount of parameters in method signature)

Comment: Multiple parameters would be better???

Comment: @devNull yes, to reduce amount of parameters in method signature and another fact is UnitTests. when you change method parameters, you will also need to fix your unit tests otherwise all of the unit tests that consume this method will throw a compilation error.

Comment: @blogs4t Why do you want it to break at runtime instead of generating a compile time error when you change the input your method needs to function?  Unless a parameter is optional, in which case, there's a language feature specifically for optional parameters.

Comment: Use some refactoring tool to change the method signature instead. This allows you some control on how the callers should be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is this a good idea or if bad

This is in the vast majority of cases a very bad idea. The caller will have no idea what parameters are needed. You cannot pass any typed object, so you lose all type safety. You will have no compiler checks to catch potential errors. You are also likely to reduce performance if that is a concern.

> what would be a better approach than this?

In most cases, regular parameters. In some cases, where you have way to many parameters, and is unable to refactor the method, a parameter object that gathers many different parameters might be motivated. The only use case I can think of for something like this is when you are getting untyped parameters from some source, for example, key-value pairs from a database or file.

If the problem is breaking builds due to signature changed, that is intentional. The compiler saves you from shooting yourself in the foot. Good refactoring tools, like R# allows modification of signatures, but if you add a parameter, chances are you need to fix call sites by hand.